# Putting year() directly into a array

Tags: arrays, processing.js

I am currently creating a array that holds a bunch of different data. One of the data points is to hold the most recent date accessed. For some reason I can't put year() into the array without the program breaking. Code below.

```
world_saves.push([[year()]]);
```

What's the reasoning behind this, and how do I set put the year into the array without a error. I've tried defining year() into a variable, but once again I get a error. Error below.

```
World_Data.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:
For anyone viewing this, this is the correct code to use.

```
var pjs = new Processing();
world_saves.push([[pjs.year()]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that I've never used [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), it appears that you have to instantiate an instance of it first before calling methods on it.
Something like:

```
var pjs = new Processing();
world_saves.push([[pjs.year()]]);
```

**also note**:  You do realize you're pushing an array of an array containing the year here, right? (vs. just `world_saves.push(pjs.year());`)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already got this sorted out, but just for your information: with Processing.js, typically you'd write Processing code and have Processing.js create the `Processing` instance and call the `setup()` and `draw()` functions for you. There are a ton of ways to do this (many are outline on [this](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html) page), but the basics would look like this:

```
<script src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">

int[] worldSaves = new int[1]; 

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  worldSaves[0] = year();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  text(worldSaves[0], 10, 10);
}

</script>
<canvas id="pjs"> </canvas>
```

What you came up with isn't really wrong or anything, but I also don't know why you're using Processing.js if you aren't using the Processing part of it. So eventually you might end up with something more like the above.